# how do i re-order bitbake tasks within a recipe

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

I am using bitbake (within Yocto) and I have a situation where I need to use 'autotools' however I need to run:

```
do_patch
```

*after*

```
do_configure
```

I have tried many things and cannot get it to do this.  It mostly complains about "circular dependencies" (probably well within reason)

Ideally, I'd like to see something like this:

```
rmtask do_patch
addtask do_patch after do_configure before do_compile
```

or

```
movetask do_patch after do_configure
```

Sadly, there seems to be no 'rmtask' or 'deltask' or 'movetask' keywords.

Any tricks for re-ordering the default tasks would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. If what you're trying to do is to patch the files **generated** during do_configure I would suggest that you fix the configure.ac and/or the Makefile.am files instead. That way it's going to be easier when you upgrade your yocto version.
2. Add a new task with `addtask` and just call the `patch` command. See the [pkgconfig](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb?h=dora) recipe for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion: delete the patch task and create a new patch task that does exactly the same and add it where it should be executed.

```
deltask do_patch
python do_patch_new () {
    bb.build.exec_func('patch_do_patch', d)
}

addtask do_patch_new after do_configure before do_compile
```

*Note*: 
The original `do_patch` task was found by inspecting `bitbake -e the_recipe`:

```
python do_patch () {
    bb.build.exec_func('patch_do_patch', d)
}
```

If it is done this way, obviously the originial patch task will be gone and one cannot patch any originally fetched sources. When creating an *additional* patch task, this will not work.